# Teams App suddenly fails directly after login - worked 3 days ago

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a custom app for teams, that was running smoothly until recently.
From one day to another, login for the app does not work anymore.
Via MSAL we use the account that is logged into teams for our application.

When I start the app, the popup shows up to check everything with ms, and normally it works from there.
However, now teamsfx logs the following

```
[Thu, 27 Jul 2023 12:20:53 GMT] : @microsoft/teamsfx : Verbose - Validate authentication configuration
bundle.js:217256 [Thu, 27 Jul 2023 12:20:53 GMT] : @microsoft/teamsfx : Info - Popup login page to get user's access token with scopes: User.Read User.ReadBasic.All
Thu, 27 Jul 2023 12:20:54 GMT] : @microsoft/teamsfx : Verbose - Get SSO token from memory cache
bundle.js:217256 [Thu, 27 Jul 2023 12:20:54 GMT] : @microsoft/teamsfx : Verbose - Get SSO token from memory cache
2bundle.js:217256 [Thu, 27 Jul 2023 12:20:54 GMT] : @microsoft/teamsfx : Info - Get access token with scopes: api://4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app/65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc/access_as_user
2bundle.js:217256 [Thu, 27 Jul 2023 12:20:54 GMT] : @microsoft/teamsfx : Verbose - Failed to call acquireTokenSilent. Reason: no_account_error: No account object provided to acquireTokenSilent and no active account has been set. Please call setActiveAccount or provide an account on the request.. 

authorize:88 Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://teams.microsoft.com' from frame with URL 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/117b6a1f-7551-4808-9200-2d40efd74c47/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc&scope=api%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2F65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2Fblank-auth-end.html&client-request-id=6c08233a-d51a-4e67-93fa-33fadf622d8b&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.38.0&client_info=1&code_challenge=Uc3BTLavkI5U27bEYqqczPAuowUbUQznSs5rEuwJUDc&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&login_hint=admindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&X-AnchorMailbox=UPN%3Aadmindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=07e49404-fbf9-48a2-985b-d37a2cc7d811&state=eyJpZCI6IjJkNTMxNmYzLTZiNGQtNGM0Ny1hM2NhLTA4MDFkMzNmYjg0MSIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoic2lsZW50In19'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

(anonymous) @ authorize:88
(anonymous) @ authorize:88
authorize:88 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/117b6a1f-7551-4808-9200-2d40efd74c47/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc&scope=api%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2F65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2Fblank-auth-end.html&client-request-id=6c08233a-d51a-4e67-93fa-33fadf622d8b&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.38.0&client_info=1&code_challenge=Uc3BTLavkI5U27bEYqqczPAuowUbUQznSs5rEuwJUDc&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&login_hint=admindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&X-AnchorMailbox=UPN%3Aadmindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=07e49404-fbf9-48a2-985b-d37a2cc7d811&state=eyJpZCI6IjJkNTMxNmYzLTZiNGQtNGM0Ny1hM2NhLTA4MDFkMzNmYjg0MSIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoic2lsZW50In19&iframe-request-id=2d9cf3fc-d706-428b-80da-eec903770200'.
    at https://login.microsoftonline.com/117b6a1f-7551-4808-9200-2d40efd74c47/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc&scope=api%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2F65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2Fblank-auth-end.html&client-request-id=6c08233a-d51a-4e67-93fa-33fadf622d8b&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.38.0&client_info=1&code_challenge=Uc3BTLavkI5U27bEYqqczPAuowUbUQznSs5rEuwJUDc&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&login_hint=admindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&X-AnchorMailbox=UPN%3Aadmindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=07e49404-fbf9-48a2-985b-d37a2cc7d811&state=eyJpZCI6IjJkNTMxNmYzLTZiNGQtNGM0Ny1hM2NhLTA4MDFkMzNmYjg0MSIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoic2lsZW50In19:88:326
    at https://login.microsoftonline.com/117b6a1f-7551-4808-9200-2d40efd74c47/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc&scope=api%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2F65f93e97-ad61-4699-abcb-39bc284cddcc%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F4cec-87-138-143-181.ngrok-free.app%2Fblank-auth-end.html&client-request-id=6c08233a-d51a-4e67-93fa-33fadf622d8b&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.38.0&client_info=1&code_challenge=Uc3BTLavkI5U27bEYqqczPAuowUbUQznSs5rEuwJUDc&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&login_hint=admindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&X-AnchorMailbox=UPN%3Aadmindme%40lintradme.onmicrosoft.com&nonce=07e49404-fbf9-48a2-985b-d37a2cc7d811&state=eyJpZCI6IjJkNTMxNmYzLTZiNGQtNGM0Ny1hM2NhLTA4MDFkMzNmYjg0MSIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoic2lsZW50In19:88:330
```

The login stuff is basically happening in a wrapping component (with some additional microsoft graph toolkit stuff)

```
...
 const { teamsfx } = useTeamsFx({
    authorityHost: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
    tenantId: 'common',
    initiateLoginEndpoint: GetRedirectUri() + 'auth-start.html',
    clientId: GetAppId(),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (teamsfx) {
      Providers.globalProvider = new TeamsFxProvider(teamsfx, basicScopes);
      teamsfx.login(basicScopes).then(function () {
        app.getContext().then((context) => {
          setCurrentLanguage(context.app.locale.indexOf('de') == 0 ? 'de' : 'en');
          setTeamsFx(teamsfx);

          Providers.globalProvider.setState(ProviderState.SignedIn);
          setDone(true);
        });
      });
    }
  }, [teamsfx]);
...
```

Later when, everything went trough and some basic data was received from my api, I'll notify teams the success to show the app.

I can see everything is running fine when inspecting the teamsfx parameter, such as sso tokens, identity and so on.

Updating to the most recent packages for teamsfx, teamsfx-react and teams-js did not help, nor do I have an idea after a lot of fiddling and thinking why it suddenly happens.

Anybody got problems recently too?
Thanks in advance

Comment: From out of nowhere, it just worked again..... /closed